# Need help getting this recursive function working

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, depth-first-search

I have an object person which defines a person at location x, y

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Person({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)

    # creates a duplicate of Person at a new x, y -> x_new, y_new
    def next(self, x_movement, y_movement):
        # this is not how the actual movement is calculated, but works for demonstration
        return Person(self.x + x_movement, self.y + y_movement)
```

I desire to find all possible movements for this person, t_steps in the future.
The possible movements are bounded by an array (that may be different at any given time, so this is an example).

x_possible = [-1, 0, 1] Note: during another run of code it could be [3, 5, 2, 4] so the algorithm needs to use this array to know possible movements.

y_possible = [-1, 0, 1]

the method call is like so:

```py
initial_person = Person(0, 0)
# all possible movements for person, 3 time steps into the future
all_possible_movements_for_person = get_possible_movements(initial_person , 3)
```

the method `get_possible_movements` must return an array of tuples where each tuple is structured like so:

```
(
x_new = FIRST movement of x from this branch of movements,
y_new = FIRST movement of y from this branch of movements,
next Person from the initial_person --> person_2 = initial_person.next(x_new, y_new),
next Person from the person_2       --> person_3 =       person_2.next(x_possible[i] , y_possible[j],
.
.
will have a person count equal to t_step from the method call
)

example:
initial_person = Person(0, 0)
# all possible movements for person, 3 time steps into the future
all_possible_movements_for_person = get_possible_movements(initial_person , 3)
all_possible_movements_for_person contains a large array of tuples with first entry:

# I am showing the movements made on the person in the tuple for example
(-1, -1, person(-1,-1), person2(-1,-1), person3(-1,-1))
- first element is 1 because the algorithm should pick the first x_movement to be -1 based on the
possible movements array.
- second is -1 for the same reason with y movements.
- the first person in the array is from doing the operation initial_person.next(-1,-1)
- the second person in the array is from doing the operation person1.next(-1,-1)
- the third person in the array is from doing the operation person2.next(-1,-1)


following similar logic, the next tuple in the output array would be:
(-1, -1, person(-1,-1), person2(-1,-1), person4(-1,0))
the person 4 object is new and is the next entry in the y_movements array to get that person.
then
(-1, -1, person(-1,-1), person2(-1,-1), person5(-1,1))
(-1, -1, person(-1,-1), person2(-1,-1), person6(0,-1))
(-1, -1, person(-1,-1), person2(-1,-1), person7(0,0))
```

The output would look like [example](https://justpaste.it/2ja73), but keep in mind I used strings to represent the objects in this output example.

my attempt is here.... it doesn't output near what I need it to and I don't think I am even close. I suck at recursion.

```py
x_possible = [-1, 0, 1]
y_possible = [-1, 0, 1]


class Person:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Person({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)

    # creates a duplicate of Person at a new x, y -> x_new, y_new
    def next(self, x_movement, y_movement):
        # this is not how the actual movement is calculated, but works for demonstration
        return Person(self.x + x_movement, self.y + y_movement)

def get_possible_movements(c, n):
    locs = []
    get_people_recursion(c, n, n, 0, 0, locs, ())
    return locs


def get_people_recursion(person, i, time_step, a_index, b_index, locs, tup):
    if time_step < 0:
        locs.append(tup)
        return

    if a_index >= len(x_possible) or b_index >= len(y_possible):
        return

    if time_step == i:
        tup += (x_possible[a_index], y_possible[b_index])

    c_next = person.next(x_possible[a_index], y_possible[b_index])
    tup += (c_next,)

    get_people_recursion(c_next, i, time_step-1, a_index, b_index, locs, copy.deepcopy(tup))
    get_people_recursion(c_next, i, time_step, a_index + 1, b_index, locs, copy.deepcopy(tup))

all_people = get_possible_movements(Person(0, 0), 1)
print(len(all_people))
for i in all_people:
    print(i)
```

output from this:

```
(-1, -1, Person(-1, -1), Person(-2, -2))
(-1, -1, Person(-1, -1), Person(-2, -2), Person(-2, -3))
(-1, -1, Person(-1, -1), Person(-2, -2), Person(-2, -3), Person(-1, -4))
(-1, -1, Person(-1, -1), 0, -1, Person(-1, -2), Person(-1, -3))
(-1, -1, Person(-1, -1), 0, -1, Person(-1, -2), Person(-1, -3), Person(0, -4))
(-1, -1, Person(-1, -1), 0, -1, Person(-1, -2), 1, -1, Person(0, -3), Person(1, -4))
```

Diagram that may or may not help... https://prnt.sc/sliwcx

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, exactly. What is a "`C`"? Can you explain the purpose of this a bit clearer? The expected output is enormous, so maybe a simple example with input -> logic -> output would make it a bit more obvious what operation is happening. Do you have to use this `C` class and recursion? Looks like some kind of product logic which is probably best using itertools. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: class C is just an object with an a and b. call it an x and y on a Cartesian graph if you want. then calling C.next(ai,bi) will "move" C on that graph to a new location ai, bi. A new C is then returned from that method.

I guess a good way to visualize it is we are trying to get all possible "ending" locations on a graph, starting from initial_C. we want to maintain the initial movement from C_initial and that is the first two numbers in the tuple. the other C's in the tuple are all the C's used to create a path to that location.

Comment: Also note, the possible "movements" of the C are bounded to be withint the bounds of a_possible and b_possible. These are not x and y directions but something else entirely to define the "movement" of C

Comment: We can answer your questing better if you describe the real problem you are trying to solve along with your proposed solution.

Comment: working on rewriting to make it more clear.

Comment: Done with the rework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close. The trick to matching your string output is to keep a single `count` variable to build the result strings or a static class variable to count ids.

Other than that, traverse recursively and push/pop a stack to store the path. Everything else is [products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Here's the code.

```
import itertools

class Person:
    def __init__(self, n, a, b):
        self.n = n
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Person{self.n}"

def produce_c(a, b, n):
    combos = list(itertools.product(a, b))
    count = 0

    def explore(pair, path=[]):
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        path.append(Person(count, *pair))

        if len(path) == n:
            yield tuple(path)
        else:
            for pair in combos:
                yield from explore(pair, path)

        path.pop()

    for pair in combos:
        for path in explore(pair):
            yield (*pair, *path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in produce_c([-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1], 3):
        print(x)
```

Comment: You got closer to understanding I think. We need the objects in the tuples though because they will be used at a later part in the program. The program is pretty big and confusing so I tried splitting this out the best I could to show our problem. I also put together this diagram to show exactly what I am needing here. Also we need C as it is a larger object with many functions. I just stripped out everything to make this simpler. Thanks for the help!

https://prnt.sc/slhysk

Comment: No problem. I added a class and fixed a bug, but it's the same algorithm. It smells a bit oversimplified--this could be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's very easy to generate this stuff but why? If it's just a random exercise, that's cool, but I suspect it's part of some search problem or game that might have a better approach to it.

Comment: I completely redid the intro if you could take a look

Comment: OK. Other than changing the class name, it seems like this algorithm still basically does what you need, no? If not, I can easily accommodate if you don't mind letting me know what I missed.

Comment: You just add a new C/Person instance to the tuple. Each Successive person relies on the previous though. tuple (-1, -1, Person1, Person1.next(-1,-1)) is how it is supposed to be structured. and we need each possible branch off person1. The way you did it, is (-1, -1, Person1, NEW Person(x)). Does this make sense?

Comment: Also, this needs to be scalable for different levels of people in the final array, not just 3. I need to be able to define n deep

Comment: Sure, although the tuples basically encode that relationship. It's easy to add a reference to the next Person in every Person object but your code doesn't have any such field so I'm copying that. The only difference between this code and yours is where the objects are created. AFAICT, `next` is totally superfluous--the caller can easily create the instance but it amounts to the same thing. If you want a `self.next = some_other_person` field, I can add that, but these don't seem like fundamental adjustments.

Comment: You are awesome! Not exactly what I needed but close enough I figured it out. a few modifications to your script here: https://justpaste.it/4hb8c .Also, I need the next def in Person class because in my actual code the relationship between the two is based on a few calculations and algorithms that are performed in the next method.

Comment: Can't say I understand what is going on fully, as I am new to python but thank you! I am going to read up on iterTools and stuff.